# How do I convert byte array to io. stream and convert it back to byte array?

Tags: go, io

```
func main(){    
bytearray:=[]byte{"data"}
reader := bytes.NewReader(stdout.Bytes())
transfer(reader)
}

Function 2
func transfer(reader *Reader){
bytearray:= //How do I get the original byte array?
}
```

Basically I want to send byte array from one function to another using readers or writers

Comment: Why do you want to use readers/writers for this? Normally readers and writers re used for passing data to/from other processes or computers as in over a network. Not between functions in the same program.

Comment: Well for the sake of the example i was same program but my use case is actually as you mentioned above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[bytes.Buffer](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer) is what you need. It can convert a byte slice to an io.Reader/io.Writer:

```
buf := bytes.NewBuffer([]bytes{...})
```

And to read from an io.Reader into a byte slice:

```
s, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r)
```

Converting to/from byte arrays is left as a trivial exercise for the reader.